# In R, need help understanding index locations within a vector vs the values within a factor, particularly within the context of loops

Tags: r, indexing

Below, I have two examples of the same code with slight changes. The first works the second does not. I am hoping by clarifying why the second does not work I will understand exactly how to quickly interpret expressions as referencing index locations vs values in those locations. ## Heading ##

Find the sum of all number < 1000 that are divisible by 3 or 5:

---VERSION A (this code works)

```
x <- 0
i <- 1
    while (i < 1e3) {
    if (i %% 3 == 0 | i %% 5 == 0) {
    x <- c(x, i)
    }
i <- i + 1
}
sum(x)
```

--VERSION B (this code does not work)

```
x <- 0
i <- 1
    while (x[i] < 1e3)       #I changed i to x[i] because I'm asking it to loop while 
                             #the value of vector x in location i is < 1e3; if i 
                             #had i < 1e3 to me it looks like I'm telling it to run as long 
                             # as we are in index location < 1e3.

    if (x[i] %% 3 == 0 | x[i] %% 5 == 0) #I added brackets here because we are saying that if 
                                 #the value   in index location i in vector x is divisible 
                                 #by 3 or 5 then proceed to next line and take indicated actions.#

    x <- c(x, x[i])         #again, here I changed i to x[i] because i want to add the 
                            # new  value   we created to the vector x.  
  }
  i <- i + 1
  }
  sum(x)
```

What am I missing here? Is it that if() and the various loop functions have limitations or interpretations of different kinds (e.g. some can only digest one number at a time while others are inherently designed to process full vectors of any length?)?

In advance, thanks for your help.

Comment: Why do you use loops at all?  A more R like way would be to write something like `sum(x[x %% 3 == 0 | x %% 5 == 0])`

Comment: Good question. I'm new to programing and new to R. It's been a steep learning curve, but I'm enjoying the learning and willing to do the heavy lifting. Any suggestions for strategy to follow for deciding what R way to use to solve a problem? Thanks for your quick replies.

Answer (score 0):

In version B, you keep adding 0 to `x` which causes an infinite loop (at least when you put in the opening braces for the `while` and `if`).  Version B will only work if you have an appropriate `x`.

I strongly suggest taking paper and writing out what happens at each iteration of the while loop.  That will help you understand what is going on.

For the current data,

```
i is 1
x[i] is x[1] is 0
x[1] %% 3 is 0 so x becomes c(0, x[1]) which is c(0, 0)
i becomes 2
```

Then the next iteration:

```
i is 2
x[i] is x[2] is 0
x[2] %% 3 is 0 so x becomes c(x, x[2]) which is c(0, 0, 0)
i becomes 3
```

and so on.  There are more idiomatic ways of doing this than a while loop (which are rare in R code), but since this is a Project Euler question, I won't describe it.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions about writing out what happens. I've started to do this and can usually test my assumptions for simple steps in R studio.

Comment: Also, `print()` can be very helpful to understand the current state of a loop.

Answer (score 0):

First, as Andrie points out, the R-way to do this is by vectorizing:

```
y <- 1:1e3
sum(y[y%%3==0 | y%%5==0])
```

Now to answer your question. You start with x=0. Then the only way x can change is by appending x[i]: `x <- c(x, x[i])`. You just append 0's and you get an endless loop. Below you find a version of your code that works. However, this is only to show you how your code can be changed to run properly and is not the recomended way to calculate your result. Please use the vectorized code instead.

```
x <- 0 # x will be the vector of all number < 1000
y <- 0 # y will be your vector of all number < 1000 that are divisible by 3 or 5
i <- 1 # index that increases
while (x[i] < 1e3)  { # while the last element of x is less than 1000
  if (x[i] %% 3 == 0 | x[i] %% 5 == 0){  
    y <- c(y, x[i]) # this changes the numbers divisible by 3 or 5
  }
  x <- c(x, x[i]+1) # this adds the next element to x, so x[i+1] exists
  i <- i+1 # adds to i
}
sum(y)
```